# line break are not working when editing a post

Tags: editor, line-breaks

So I have a problem when making a post. If I press enter and make a new line in the editor and press safe the line break diapers. But when I show the post it have inserted a line break. So somehow the editor is not able to show the line break? If I save the editor again the line break disappears from the post as well.

Any ideas?

I read in a post to try and use:

```
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

Which I did and now line breaks don't work at all. 
I have build a custom page where the posts are shown with the

```
echo the_content();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah sorry I just realized that I had margin: 0 on all elements to reset all defaults in browsers... this caused the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You've stumbled across a 'hidden' feature of WordPress and TinyMCE (the visual editor) it has a problem with line breaks and strips them out.

Try either of these two plugins:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/line-break-shortcode/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-breaks/

Comment: There is no way to handle this in any other way? Like editing the code for the editor and put like a nl2br() around the content?

Comment: there are comments on WordPress.org about this - but it's not a good idea to hack the core code of WordPress. You could break your WP install & your hack would be deleted next time you try to update to a new version.

Comment: That is so true Damien... I am just very frustrated about this simple issue :)

Comment: It's actually a 'good' feature which prevents users from adding unsafe HTML code via Tiny MCE and its from an assumption that people pressing Enter key want a paragraph break.

Comment: did you try this ... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: What would that do? It would still not show the line break in the editor?

Comment: The problem is that my users are not used to work with computers. They wont understand that the line break they just made disappears when they save the text. The content when shown have the line break but if they edit like a spelling error and save the text again the line break would disappear.

Comment: Ah sorry I just realized that I had margin: 0 on all elements to reset all defaults in browsers... this caused the issue!